# Given 2 coordinates, draw a line between them

Tags: python, coordinates, linear-algebra

I have given two coordinates (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) and would like to draw a line between them given a function drawdot(x,y). So to make it look like I draw a line I just want to draw 100 dots between the two points. How would I do this , I guesse its just a y = ax + b problem but I just can't manage to make it work.

thx

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the unitary vector from point `A` to point `B` and then scale it `n` times.

Ill make a function that **returns** the points (pair of coordinates) that need to be drawn.

```
def drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, n):
    v = (x2 - x1, y2 - y1)
    length = math.sqrt(v[0]**2, v[1]**2)
    unitary = (v[0]/length, v[1]/length)
    return [(x1 + unitary[0]*i, y1 + unitary[1]*i) for i in range(n)]
```